# Emulator doesn't start on level below than API 22

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I installed **Lubuntu 16.04** operating system and **Android Studio 2.0** on it.

First thing after that I created an `Hello World` project in AS for testing. After loading emulator with `AVD Galaxy Nexus API 23` successfully I tried to do the same thing with  `AVD Galaxy Nexus API 16` but the emulator didn't started (only showing the beginning process and then after 5 minutes stopped because of not responding). I also tried with other AVD like Nexus One and so on but without success.

In Ubuntu 16.04 OS there were no problems with that (it worked even with *nouveau* driver wich in Lubuntu didn't, in Lubuntu I was forced to load my *nvidia* driver because it didn't even started because it couldn't find the driver).

*How can I resolve this issue?*

**P.S.** In SDK manager I downloaded everything it showed me to download/upgrade, I even download packages for API 16 (which in Ubuntu I never did but everything were working fine).

Answer (score 0):

In your AVD settings Please change the minimum and target sdk levels below the 23 and then run for different AVD's

Comment: The minimum sdk level is 15 and the target is 23.

Comment: check the RAM sizes of your AVD's

Comment: I gave the RAM of 1 GB or by default the AS gave itself. Anyway I installed Elementary OS and everything worked fine (and performance is quite nice, almost as Lubuntu's). Thanks for feedback.

Comment: welcome Andritchi Alexei feel free to ask any help from this community